# Mod rewrite rule for url with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, getparameter, clean-url

I have a domain called wwww.website.com. There, I have a subdirectory called www.website.com/register.

In this directory, I have a .htaccess file, which redirect urls for example likes this:

```
www.webseite.com/register/confirmation
```

to

```
www.webseite.com/register/confirmation.php
```

Now, what I want is a redirection like this:

```
www.webseite.com/register/verification/454654/12345
```

to

```
www.webseite.com/register/verification.php?a=454654&b=12345
```

At the moment, my .htaccess file is located in the register directory, and lokks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Does anybody know, how i have to modify this .htaccess file?

Thank you,

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^verification/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ verification.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow, this answer came quickly.Thank you very much!